# Search for elements that matches a pattern in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like `sub_category-21,cross_category-23,sub_category-33,sub_category-93,cross_category-69`.

I want to obtain the numbers for sub_category and the ones for cross category.

What I've done since now is seperate it in an array:

```
$categories = explode(",", $_POST["categories"]);

$sub_categories = array();
$cross_categories = array();

foreach($categories as $category)
{

}
```

How I can do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression is probably the most convenient solution here (you will also not need to worry about whitespace etc):

```
$str = 'sub_category-21,cross_category-23,sub_category-33,'.
       'sub_category-93,cross_category-69';
preg_match_all('/(sub|cross)_category-([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);

$categories = array('sub' => array(), 'cross' => array());
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $categories[$match[1]][] = $match[2];
}

print_r($categories);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/Vux0f)**.

This code puts the results in `$categories['sub']` and `$categories['cross']` instead of into two separate variables as in your example for convenience. It's easy to change it if you want it done differently.

You can also do it with nested `explode`:

```
$str = 'sub_category-21,cross_category-23,sub_category-33,'.
       'sub_category-93,cross_category-69';

$categories = array();

foreach(explode(',', $str) as $category) {
    list($type, $id) = explode('-', trim($category));
    $categories[$type][] = $id;
}

print_r($categories);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/2g6Qi)**.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into the foreach-loop, just as a simple idea

```
$category_strpos = strpos($category, "cross_category-")
    if($category_strpos == 0 && $category_strpos !== FALSE)
        $cross_categories[] = str_replace("cross_category-", "", $category);
$sub_strpos = strpos($category, "sub_category-")
    if($sub_strpos == 0 && $sub_strpos !== FALSE)
        $sub_categories[] = str_replace("sub_categories-", "", $category);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at split function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php.

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $split1=split("-",$category);
    $num=$split1[1];
    $name=$split1[0];
    if($name=="sub_category"){
        array_push($sub_categories,$num);
    }
    if($name=="cross_category"){
        array_push($cross_categories,$num);
    }
}
```